# ERROR [main] (00000021-ImpEx-Import) [ImpExImportJob] Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes

Tags: impex

[java] INFO  [main] [ImpExSystemSetup] importing resource : /impex/essentialdata_mediaconversion_jobs.impex
     [java] INFO  [main] (00000021-ImpEx-Import) [ImpExImportJob] Starting multi-threaded ImpEx cronjob "ImpEx-Import" (8 threads)
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<2/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 2/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<3/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 3/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<4/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 4/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<5/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 5/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<6/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 6/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<7/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 7/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<0/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 0/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<1/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 1/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [impex result worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import]] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex result worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [main] (00000021-ImpEx-Import) [Importer] Finished 1 pass in 0d 00h:00m:00s:027ms - processed: 4, dumped: 1 (last pass: 0)
     [java] INFO  [impex reader worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import]] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex reader worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [main] (00000021-ImpEx-Import) [Importer] Starting pass 2
     [java] INFO  [ImpExWorker<0/8>] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex worker 0/8 [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] WARN  [impex result worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import]] [ImpExImportReader] line 2 at main script: dumped unresolved line ValueLine[unresolvable:null,line 2 at main script,∩╗┐,null,{1=ValueEntry('# no current header for value line'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false)}]
     [java] INFO  [impex result worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import]] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex result worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] INFO  [main] (00000021-ImpEx-Import) [Importer] Finished 2 pass in 0d 00h:00m:00s:001ms - processed: 1, dumped: 1 (last pass: 1)
     [java] INFO  [impex reader worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import]] [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex reader worker [cj:00000021-ImpEx-Import] to the pool
     [java] WARN  [main] (00000021-ImpEx-Import) [Importer] Import aborted after 0d 00h:00m:00s:068ms
     [java] ERROR [main] (00000021-ImpEx-Import) [ImpExImportJob] Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 1 lines!
     [java] ERROR [main] [ImpExManager] Import has caused an error, see logs of cronjob with code=00000021-ImpEx-Import for further details

Comment: hey did you resolved this error ? if you yes can you please tell me how because I've similar kind of error

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the warning

> [ImpExImportReader] line 2 at main script: dumped unresolved line ValueLine[unresolvable:null,line 2 at main script,∩╗┐,null,{1=ValueEntry('# no current header for value line'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false)}]

Impex header is not well-formed.

If you want a concrete solution, then provide original Impex text.